# There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Type' to 'Interface'

Tags: c#, ninject

I have three interfaces:

```
internal interface IAmAnInterfaceOne
{
    int PropertyOne { get; set; }
}

internal interface IAmAnInterfaceTwo
{
    int PropertyTwo { get; set; }
}

internal interface IAmAnInterfaceCombiningOneAndTwo : IAmAnInterfaceOne, IAmAnInterfaceTwo
{
}
```

Implementation class:

```
internal class Myimplementation : IAmAnInterfaceOne, IAmAnInterfaceTwo
{
    public int PropertyOne { get; set; }
    public int PropertyTwo { get; set; }
}
```

When I tried to bind interface `IAmAnInterfaceCombiningOneAndTwo` to `Myimplementation`, I got error:

> There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Type' to 'Interface'

```
class AppModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IAmAnInterfaceCombiningOneAndTwo>().To<Myimplementation>().InSingletonScope();
    }
}
```

I want to use it in constructor like that:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly IAmAnInterfaceCombiningOneAndTwo _param;

    public MyClass(IAmAnInterfaceCombiningOneAndTwo param)
    {
        _param = param;
    }
}
```

How to bind interface properly?
Thanks.

Comment: Now I see. I changed `Myimplementation : IAmAnInterfaceOne, IAmAnInterfaceTwo` to `Myimplementation : IAmAnInterfaceCombiningOneAndTwo` and it works. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Will add an answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a Ninject error.

```
IAmAnInterfaceCombiningOneAndTwo obj = new Myimplementation();
```

The above code wouldn't compile. Why? Because `Myimplementation` doesn't implement `IAmAnInterfaceCombiningOneAndTwo`. It implements `IAmAnInterfaceOne` and `IAmAnInterfaceTwo`.

`IAmAnInterfaceCombiningOneAndTwo` requires that these two are implemented, but merely implementing them doesn't also mean that the implementer implements the combination interface. It's technically a different interface altogether. Indeed, you could add further requirements to the combination interface that neither `IAmAnInterfaceOne` nor `IAmAnInterfaceTwo` include.

The simplest solution is to change `Myimplementation` to explicitly declare that it implements the combination interface (either additionally, or just that interface - the net effect is the same):

```
internal class Myimplementation : IAmAnInterfaceCombiningOneAndTwo
```